# Evento Onclick no defnido

Tags: javascript, html5, firebase, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-storage

Hola estoy empezando a trabajar con firebase y quiero hacer uso de storage para subir una foto o cualqueir docuemnto, solo que alperecer mi funcion onclick no esta definida a lo cual no logro entedner talvez estoy olvidando algo:

```html
<div>
    <h3>Subir Archivo</h3>
    <input type="file" id="fileToUpload">
    <hr>
    <button onclick="subirArchivo()">Subir</button>
</div>

<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js";
    import { } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-storage.js';
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {

    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    async function subirArchivo() {
        inputFile = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
        if (inputFile.files.length == 0) {
            alert("Por favor seleciona un archivo");
            return
        } else {
            let file = inputFile.files[0];
            let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(file.name);
            await storageRef.put(file);
            console.log("Terminó la descarga...");

            abrirArchivo(file.name);
        }
    }

    async function abrirArchivo(path) {
        let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(path);
        let url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
        window.open(url);
    }
</script>
```

Elimine la parte de firebaseConfig ya que se supone es personal pero si la nececitan diganme, este es el error que arroja la consola:
index.html:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: subirArchivo is not defined

Answer (score 1):

### Problema

El problema está en que estás declarando el script como un [módulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type) `type=module`, lo que hace que el alcance del código que escribes quede dentro del mismo.

Es por eso que obtienes un `ReferenceError` o error de referencia. Ya que fuera de dicho módulo no existe la función `subirArchivo`.

### Solución

- Para solucionar esto puedes declarar globalmente la función `subirArchivo` agregándola dentro del objeto `window` de la siguiente manera:

```html
<script type="module">
//...
    async function subirArchivo() {
        inputFile = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
        if (inputFile.files.length == 0) {
            alert("Por favor seleciona un archivo");
            return
        } else {
            let file = inputFile.files[0];
            let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(file.name);
            await storageRef.put(file);
            console.log("Terminó la descarga...");

            abrirArchivo(file.name);
        }
    }
    window.subirArchivo = subirArchivo;
</script>
```

Para usarlo:

```html
<div>
    <h3>Subir Archivo</h3>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="subirArchivo()">Ejecutar función</button>
</div>
<script type="module">
//...
    async function subirArchivo() {
       console.log("hola");
    }
    window.subirArchivo = subirArchivo;
</script>
```

---

- También podrías usar un `eventListener` dentro del script.

Esto sería:

```html
<h3>Subir Archivo</h3>
<hr>
<button id="subir">Subir</button>
<script type="module">
  async function subirArchivo() {
     console.log("hola");
  }

  document.querySelector('#subir')
    .addEventListener('click', subirArchivo);
</script>
```

### Anexos

Puedes ver mas sobre módulos [aquí](https://usefulangle.com/post/256/script-type-module-vs-script-javascript).

Para ejemplificar esto del alcance dentro y fuera de un módulo veamos el siguiente ejemplo:

```html
<script type="module">
    // esta función está disponible solo en este bloque <script>
    function myFunc() {
        console.log("Myfunc ejecutada correctamente");
    }
  console.log("llamo a myFunc() correctamente");
  myFunc();
</script>

<script type="module">
    // reference error : myFunc is not defined
  console.log("llamo a myFunc() con error de referencia");
    myFunc(); // myFunc no está definida en este bloque <script> ya que es otro módulo distinto
</script>
```